# How to set date in mysql select

Tags: mysql

I have Mysql table:

```
id | deadline   | days 
1  | 1423695600 | 0
2  | 1426705199 | 1,2,3
```

I want: if days filed is 0, change deadline to today's date but keep old hour and minute
I have tried but i dont know how to bulid query

```
SELECT id IF(p.days != 0, deadline) as deadline, days FROM posts
```

Comment: 1. See normalization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to convert from unix time stamps to regular date times for this operation:

```
select addtime(date(now()), time(from_unixtimestamp(deadline))
```

You can get back a unix time stamp:

```
select unix_timestamp(addtime(date(now()), time(from_unixtimestamp(deadline)))
```

Comment: could write full query? This is not working IF(p.days != 0, (SELECT unix_timestamp(addtime(date(now()), time(from_unixtimestamp(deadline)))) as deadline)

Answer (score 1):

Try **Case**:

SELECT stock.name, 
    CASE 
         WHEN stock.quantity <20 THEN 'Buy urgent'
         ELSE 'There is enough'
      END
FROM stock